# Вызов метода из обьекта

Tags: php

Не могу понять конструкцию кода в `php`. Где можно подробно прочитать, как работает такой вызов, с примерами?

```
$phone = Project_User::getRegion()->getSitePhone();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про конструкцию `Proejct_User::getRegion()` можно прочитать, например, [здесь](http://myrusakov.ru/php-static.html). Если говорить коротко, то таким образом вызывается статичный метод класса `Proejct_User`. И по следующей конструкции: `->getSitePhone()` можно сказать о том, что метод `getRegion()` возвращает какой-то объект, а потом у этого объекта вызывается метод `getSitePhone()`.